# Can anyone identify this port?

Tags: port, desktop-computer, connector

There is a port on the front of my computer behind a little trap door. It is separated into two parts, one with 7 pins and one with 15 pins. Does anyone know what this port is for?

![Port on front of desktop PC, 7-pin/15-pin][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEJj0.jpg[image: port][image: front panel trapdoor][image: opened panel][image]

Comment: Please provide a photo of the port itself. And not just a (blurry) panel.

Comment: It's a SATA port and SATA power, looks like you could plug in a 2.5" drive there, the ports are matching to a drive of that form factor

Comment: It does look like a SATA plug, but if you put a little 2.5" drive, it would be dangerously hanging out in the air, ready to disconnect at a moment's notice.  And a 3.5" hard drive wouldn't be able to fit in the surrounding fascia, let alone hold its own weight up against gravity.  Weird to put that on the front of a PC.

Comment: Searching around, I found mSATA that seemed to look similar to this. Would it be for an mSATA or is this for hooking up a whole HDD or SDD?

Comment: @RyanHibbs - Please identify which APEVIA computer case you have exactly.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage - Except that’s exactly what the bay is designed for, 2.5” and 3.5” mechanical SATA HDDS, considering it’s a hot swappable port that makes sense.

Comment: @Ramhound , the image was replaced in an edit.  The original photo was zoomed in on the 2.5" and showed only the plug itself, without demonstrating the surrounding bay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what this port is for?

According to the specifications for your case, it's a 2.5" or 3.5" hot-swappable SATA HDD drive bay.

> Our X-Dreamer 4 provides the same quality and similar design as our previous X-Dreamer cases with some extra flash. An updated design makes this case appear more sleek and modern than the previous models with the power and reset switches encircling the front LCD temperature readout. This rock solid chassis features front accessible USB2.0 ports, a USB3.0 port, and high definition audio ports for easy use of peripherals, innovative 5.25" drop-down doors unify the color of the front panel, and built-in 120mm and 200mm fans add a nice breeze to your system. **In addition, we have included a hot-swappable drive bay for either an external 3.5" or 2.5" hard drive.** Our stunning X-Dreamer 4 is unbeatable on its value and quality.

[image]

Source:

- [X-Dreamer4-BL](https://www.apevia.com/products-cases/x-dreamer4-bl)
- [X-Dream4-BL User Manual](https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ced3cdc3850586f0800b1a0/5d800151ada7fe599a3f8278_um-x-dreamer4.pdf)